Model structure in diagram categories
While trying to understand the model structure in a category of dg-modules over a dga, I found the following excerpt from Toën's [The homotopy theory of dg-categories and derived  Morita theory]:
... the above definition endows $C-Mod$ with a structure of a cofibrantly generated model category (see for example [Hi, 11]). The natural $C(k)$-enrichment of $C-Mod$ endows furthermore $C-Mod$ with a structure of a $C(k)$-model category in the sense of [Ho1, 4.2.18]...
This is where he defines a model structure in $C-Mod = C(k)^C$, when $C$ is a dg category.
I looked up [Hi, 11], which was constructing a cofibrantly generated model structure on $M^C$, where $M$ has a cofibrantly generated model structure and $C$ is a category.
In order to apply this to our setting, where the domain category is also a dg-category, we need some enriched version of the [Hi, 11] I suppose, but I am confused how this can be done.
I am trying to work out the case of $C$ having a single object (so $Hom(\cdot,\cdot)=A$ is a dga), but then what would be the generating cofibrations: by unraveling [Hi, 11], it seems to be something like $\left((0 \to k \to 0) \otimes A\right) \longrightarrow \left((0 \to k \to k \to 0) \otimes A\right)$, but this doesn't seem to agree with another characterization usually given in terms of $P$-resolutions as in Deriving DG categories.
How can I understand the above excerpt? Or there is a somewhere else that I can read about cofibrately generated model category structure on $C-Mod$?

What exactly is your question here?  You already answered your question about generating cofibrations correctly.  If your question was meant to be contained in the clause “…this doesn't seem to agree with another characterization…”, then more details are necessary about this “other characterization”.
